# How to read a MySQL table every 1 -10 seconds within a Flutter app?

Tags: mysql, flutter, socket.io, flutter-futurebuilder, fetching-strategy

I am writing a Flutter app that uses a NodeJS REST API server as it's backend. The NodeJS application also uses MySQL database to store data.

The data inside the MySQL gets updated by another application. What I want to do is to read some specific tables of the MySQL database every 1-10 seconds.

I also have a router point within the NodeJS app that I can send `http.get()` requests from my flutter app to read data from MySQL. But I don't know what is the best way of sending these kind of requests frequently?

I am also interested to know if there is a better way of doing that like using `socket.io`? Or maybe accessing the MySQL directly without using the NodeJS app?

Comment: Create a background task that fires read() after every specific interval of time. Try working with workmanager & isolates

Comment: where is mysql table? on server or on device?

Comment: @Prashant: I don't know about that. Could you give me a code snippet or a link to see how does it work?

Comment: @Rahul: I edited my question and tried to add more information. The MySQL is on the remote server and I have access to that by sending `http.get()` requests through the NodeJS backend app.